# Função unset() do PHP pode melhorar o desempenho?

Tags: php, variáveis, desempenho, memória

Eu penso que a resposta da minha pergunta seria "sim.", até por que acabo fazendo isso no meu código (quando eu me lembro), mas só parei pra pensar nisso agora e de certa forma estou preocupado se caso alguém me perguntasse sobre isso, eu não iria saber responder o "por quê" disso de forma satisfatória.

Segue um trecho de exemplo:

```
<?php
# aqui um array multidimensional com 10k de linhas
$data  = array(...);
# aqui peguei o que eu precisava da variável acima
$total = (int) count($data); 
# a partir de agora não preciso mais usar a variável $data
?>
```

A partir da linha que eu não preciso mais usar uma variável no resto do código, eu preciso apagar ela usando o `unset($data)` como no que citei acima? Isso trás alguma melhoria no desempenho de fato? Pois eu penso que o mesmo processamento que teria para carregar ela mesmo sem usar, seria o processamento de apagar ela.

Comment: Só lembrando que o `unset()` não é uma função, mas sim um construtor de linguagem. Veja [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.keywords.php) a lista.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depende do contexto pois se for mal aplicado causa efeito contrário, aumentando o uso de memória e processamento.

Veja um simples teste:

## Teste 1

Aqui usamos `unset()` para remover os índices da variável `$arr` 1 por 1.

A lógica aqui é que já estamos fazendo uma iteração em cada um dos índices então teoricamente poderia ser mais performático já ir removendo cada um, certo?

```
$arr = range(1, 100000);
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if ($k % 2 === 0) {
        $arr2[] = $v;
    }
    unset($arr[$k]);
}
```

O resultado do uso de memória:

**Pico**: 17174288 (17mb)

**Corrente**: 10883880 (10mb)

Tempo de execução (microsegundos)

**Total**: 0.0090339183807373

**Inicial**: 1469910070.9007

**Final**: 1469910070.9097

## Teste 2

Nesse segundo teste, pensamos num jeito diferente. Partindo da lógica de que cada vez que `unset()` é invocado, estaria consumindo mais memória e processamento. Como o objetivo final é apagar por completo a variável `$arr` então, podemos fazer isso invocando **unset()** somente 1 vez, após o laço de repetição.

```
$arr = range(1, 100000);
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if ($k % 2 === 0) {
        $arr2[] = $v;
    }
}
unset($arr);
```

O resultado do uso de memória:

**Pico**: 10882752 (10mb)

**Corrente**: 4592344 (4mb)

Tempo de execução (microsegundos)

**Total**: 0.0061979293823242

**Inicial**: 1469910142.5007

**Final**: 1469910142.5069

Aqui tiramos uma conclusão de que a teoria do segundo teste está correta para o contexto aqui apresentado. A invocação repetidas vezes da função `unset()`, dentro do contexto do teste, causa efeito contrário, prejudicando a performance significativamente.

O tempo de execução apresenta uma "insignificante" diferença de 0.003 micro segundos para a percepção humana, no entanto, é uma diferença relevante em termos de processamento de dados. Mas o que mais chama atenção é o consumo de memória. A função `unset()` pode sim melhorar a performance liberando espaço na memória em uso de forma significativa quando usado de forma adequada.

## Regra geral:

1. A invocação repetida de uma função gera um consumo maior.
2. Aplique `unset()` nos objetos que não serão mais usados, principalmente se ainda há mais rotinas a serem executadas. Pois assim economizará memória para o restante dos processos.

## Coletor de lixo?

Podemos argumentar que é "desnecessário" ter esse cuidado pois ao final de todos os processos, tudo "morre", mas, dependendo do contexto é sempre bom liberar espaço na memória.

O PHP possui um limitador de uso de memória, definido nas configurações (php.ini). Normalmente o padrão é entre 64mb e 128mb. Um script que chega na metade do processamento já consumindo 125mb, por exemplo, tem um risco grande de causar interrompimento da execução devido a falta de memória. Muitos desses casos de "out of memory" poderiam ser evitados se o script limpasse as variáveis que não estão sendo usadas. Por isso, é muito válido ter o cuidado em liberar o espaço na memória durante as execuções.

**Termos usados**

<sub>pico: maior quantidade de espaço usado durante a execução, ou seja o “pico de memória”</sub>

<sub>corrente: quantidade de memória sendo usada logo após o unset()</sub>

<sub>inicial e final: o tempo inicial e tempo final da execução em formato timestamp, usando a função microtime()</sub>

<sub>total: é o cálculo da diferença entre o tempo inicial e tempo final, em microsegundos.</sub>

Comment: Pico, corrente, total, inicial, final seriam o que especificamente, me desculpe sou um meio leigo?

Comment: Adicionei no final da resposta o significado desses termos.

Answer (score 7):

Na verdade, é altamente improvável que vá obter algum ganho de performance.

Este comando diz que a variável não será mais usada. Isso não aumenta performance. Até consome alguma mínima para dizer isso.

Pode-se pensar que haverá um ganho porque a memória é liberada. Isso até poderia ser verdade em circunstâncias bem específicas, onde tenha uma restrição grande de memória e a aplicação rodasse por muito tempo, o que é raro em PHP. Mas não é porque a função sequer libera a memória. No máximo permite que a liberação seja feita.

Então até seria verdade em algum caso, mas precisaria analisar ele concretamente com código real e estrutura que ele rodará.

Se encontrar uma situação que a performance é importante e há indicação clara (tem que medir) que o consumo de memória está obrigando o código fazer *swap* em disco, aí pode ser interessante dar essa solução.

Pelo menos do ponto de vista de performance, se não provar que o comando consegue um resultado necessário (de verdade), não perca tempo com isso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Lembro que eu tomei ciência disso quando um script não era executado por falta de memória, sempre aparecia *limite de memória excedido* mesmo usando toda a existente no servidor, então por esperança de solucionar o problema tentando o que fosse possível, acabei usando `unset()` na crença que algum beneficio trazia, e no meu caso, nesse especifico e raro deu certo, em outros, nenhum, bem como você citou.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

sua quantidade de memória livre não terá qualquer efeito no desempenho dos seus programas em PHP. Você terá somente mais espaço para alocar memória criando mais variáveis.

Mesmo em uma situação aonde você consumisse toda a memória disponível, isso não teria um impacto em desempenho uma vez que o interpretador do PHP limita a quantidade de memória que pode ser consumida por um processo evitando que ele degrade o sistema.

Answer (score 1):

O construtor `unset()`, não tem muito efeito ou impacto no desempenho em si, mas pode melhorar o desempenho, ao longo de um processo que esteja sendo utilizado  posteriormente, como o uso de sessão por exemplo, se você pensar de maneira global, você estará eliminando dados no processo, o que seria eliminar recursos e memória, entretanto, estará executando um novo processo para isso que usará memória, mas muito pouca, nada que vá impactar efetivamente no processo. A menos que seja mal usada como explica Daniel.

Answer (score -4):

gc_collect_cycles();//Força a coleta de quaisquer ciclos de lixo existentes. Este comando funcionou muito bem para mim em um script de longa duração. Ele limpa a memoria no momento que você quiser.

Comment: Daniel, a pergunta feita na página é *"Função unset() do PHP pode melhorar o desempenho?"* então é isso o que deve ser respondido.