# Liberar memória no php

Tags: php

É possível liberar memória no PHP?
Em um método executo algumas funções entre elas um foreach e depois que termino queria liberar memória.

Estou dando unset em algumas variáveis mas não recupera l espaço novamente.

É possível ?

Edit
Vou explicar minha intenção em liberar a memoria:

No sistema que estou desenvolvendo preciso retornar detalhes de um período  que pode chegar até 1 ano de prazo.
Mostrando dia a dia o estado de cada bloco de horário, podendo um dia ter até 96 blocos.

Parte deste código é um método que me retorna um array contendo parte deste detalhamento.

E este código está consumindo cerca de 50 megas ... Vejam o código:

```
public function getRenovacao($grades_id, $periodo_inicio, $periodo_fim, $atividades_comerciais_id) {

        Controller::startTest();
        Controller::checkPointStartTest('Laço While');

        $end_timestamp = strtotime($periodo_fim);
        $tmp_timestamp = strtotime($periodo_inicio);
        while ($tmp_timestamp <= $end_timestamp) {
            $tmp_dia_semana = (int) date("w", $tmp_timestamp);
            $tmp_data = date("Y-m-d", $tmp_timestamp);
            $periodo_array[$tmp_dia_semana][$tmp_data] = ['atividade_comercial_utilizada' => 0, 'duracao_utilizada' => 0];
            $tmp_timestamp = strtotime("+1 day", $tmp_timestamp);
        }

        Controller::checkPointEndTest();
        Controller::checkPointStartTest('Consulta banco de dados tabela "Blocos"');
        $select = 
                [
                    'blocos.grades_id',
                    'blocos.bloco',
                    'blocos.dia_semana',
                    'blocos.duracao',
                    'blocos_produtos.blocos_id',
                    'blocos_produtos.produtos_id',
                ];

        $grade_blocos = DB::table('blocos')
                ->join('blocos_produtos', 'blocos.id', '=', 'blocos_produtos.blocos_id')
                ->select($select)
                ->where('blocos.grades_id', $grades_id)
                ->get();

        $grade_blocos = json_decode(json_encode($grade_blocos),1);

        foreach ($grade_blocos as $dados) {
            if(array_key_exists($dados['dia_semana'], $periodo_array)){
                $key = (int)$dados['blocos_id'];
                $blocos[] = $dados['blocos_id'];
                $tmp_grade_blocos[$key]['id'] = $dados['blocos_id'];
                $tmp_grade_blocos[$key]['grades_id'] = $dados['grades_id'];
                $tmp_grade_blocos[$key]['bloco'] = $dados['bloco'];
                $tmp_grade_blocos[$key]['dia_semana'] = $dados['dia_semana'];
                $tmp_grade_blocos[$key]['duracao'] = $dados['duracao'];
                $tmp_grade_blocos[$key]['produtos'][] = $dados['produtos_id'];
                $tmp_grade_blocos[$key]['programacao'] = $periodo_array[$dados['dia_semana']];
            }
        }
        $grade_blocos = array_values($tmp_grade_blocos);
        $blocos = array_unique($blocos);

        unset($periodo_array, $tmp_grade_blocos, $tmp_data, $tmp_dia_semana, $tmp_timestamp,$end_timestamp);

        Controller::checkPointEndTest();
        Controller::checkPointStartTest('Consulta banco de dados tabela "Comerciais"');


        $blocos_tempo = DB::table('comerciais')
                ->join('produtos', 'comerciais.produtos_id', '=', 'produtos.id')
                ->select('blocos_id', 'atividades_comerciais_id', 'data', 'produtos.duracao')
                ->whereIn('blocos_id', $blocos)
                ->where('data', '>=', $periodo_inicio)
                ->where('data', '<=', $periodo_fim)
                ->get();

        Controller::checkPointEndTest();
        Controller::checkPointStartTest('Laço Foreach Final');

        foreach ($blocos_tempo as $dados) {
            $id = $dados->blocos_id;
            $grade_blocos_id = array_search($id, array_column($grade_blocos, 'id'));

            $tmp_data = $dados->data;
            $tmp_atividades = (int)$grade_blocos[$grade_blocos_id]["programacao"][$tmp_data]['atividade_comercial_utilizada'];
            if($dados->atividades_comerciais_id == $atividades_comerciais_id){
                $tmp_atividades++; 
            }

            $tmp_duracao_utilizada = (int)$grade_blocos[$grade_blocos_id]["programacao"][$tmp_data]['duracao_utilizada'] + (int)$dados->duracao;
            $grade_blocos[$grade_blocos_id]["programacao"][$tmp_data] =
                                                                        [
                                                                            'atividade_comercial_utilizada' => $tmp_atividades,
                                                                            'duracao_utilizada' => $tmp_duracao_utilizada
                                                                        ];
        }

        Controller::checkPointEndTest();
        Controller::endTest();
        //die();
        $return['grades_id'] = $grades_id;
        $return['blocos'] = $grade_blocos;
```

As onde tem checkPoint e test são funções estáticas apenas para medir o consumo, eu mesmo as fiz para saber qual trecho do código melhorar ... Vejam o resultado:

> Laço While
>       -----------------------------------------------------
>       Tempo de execução: 0.00576 s.
>       Memoria inicial: 9.25 MB.
>       Memoria Final: 9.5 MB.
>       Memoria Utilizada: 0.25 MB.
>       -----------------------------------------------------
>
> ```
> Consulta banco de dados tabela "Blocos"
> -----------------------------------------------------
> Tempo de execução: 0.0788 s.
> Memoria inicial: 9.5 MB.
> Memoria Final: 18.75 MB.
> Memoria Utilizada: 9.25 MB.
> -----------------------------------------------------
>
> Consulta banco de dados tabela "Comerciais"
> -----------------------------------------------------
> Tempo de execução: 0.54036 s.
> Memoria inicial: 18.75 MB.
> Memoria Final: 49 MB.
> Memoria Utilizada: 30.25 MB.
> -----------------------------------------------------
>
> Laço Foreach Final
> -----------------------------------------------------
> Tempo de execução: 2.20804 s.
> Memoria inicial: 49 MB.
> Memoria Final: 50.25 MB.
> Memoria Utilizada: 1.25 MB.
> -----------------------------------------------------
>
> TEMPO TOTAL DE EXECUÇÃO DO SCRIPT
> -----------------------------------------------------
> Tempo de execução: 2.83315 s.
> Memoria inicial: 9.25 MB.
> Memoria Final: 50.25 MB.
> Memoria Utilizada: 41 MB.
> ----------------------------------------------------
> ```

Comment: Relacionado: [O que acontece detalhadamente na destruição de uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22962)

Comment: A rotina de programação parece impecável, o gargalo é no banco. Tenho rotinas de sql com quase 200 linhas que consomem 300ms de execução em um sistema de publicidade que possuo. Imprima a query sql inteira e verifique também se setou corretamente os indices nas tabelas que se relacionam. A não ser que tenha me enganado isso : Tempo de execução: 0.54036 s. é segundo ou milesegundos?

Comment: 0.54 segundos é isso mesmo ?

Comment: @RafaelSalomão sim ... Pelo menos é o que está me retornando o teste neste trecho ... O estranho é que está consumindo muita memória nesta nesta query

Comment: Quantos registros tem a tabela Comerciais ? Essa tabela é myisam ou innodb?

Comment: @RafaelSalomão 151.000 registro eu uso innodb

Comment: @DanielLopes deve ser relacionado com a primeira que você fez e porque lá você não colocou a quantidade de registro, porque isso influencia.

Comment: relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143602

Answer (score 1):

Daniel não precisa se preocupar com a liberação de memória do php ele gerencia isso. Na realidade quando uma theards de apache nginx ou lighttpd roda ele executa o php como filho que executa suas rotinas php ao final da execução o retorno é devolvido ao servidor http e impresso na pagina e o próprio servidor reaproveita a cabeça de php aberta para executar outras requisições que estejam chegando no servidor. Ou se não houver necessidade encerra a theards abertas para liberar o uso de memória esse processo recebe o nome de GARBAGE COLLECTOR.

O comando:

> unset

serve apenas se quiser liberar o valor de uma variável para reutiliza-la no seu script.

PS: theards = cabeça de processamento.

Essa foi uma explicação muito superficial do funcionamento existem diversas formas de rodar o php como cgi, fastcgi por exemplo, se quiser se aprofundar procure no google formas de executar o php sobre apache ou qualquer servidor web.

---

Vou te dar várias soluções a primeira é de depuração para constatar o problema:

copie sua tabela COMERCIAIS e coloque outro nome em seguida apague boa parte de seu conteúdo assim como os registros que se relacionam com essa tabela em seguida edite seu código para o novo nome das tabelas e execute a sua rotina. Se ver o tempo despencar vai detectar aonde está o gargalo de execução ai é simples :

Solução 1 : Particione a tabela

Solução 2: Crie uma nova tabela e "pre-execute" os dados desse join com stored procedure e crie um evento no banco para ficar rodando em background atualizações, quando for executar a sua query rode por essa nova tabela uma query simples

Solução 3: Nunca usei mas sei que existe use view.

Ainda restou ter certeza que seu sql está certo, como utiliza uma classe container não tive como analisar a construção da query.

Espero que essas informações sejam utéis.

Comment: Estou preocupado pois um método que estou utilizando está gastando 50 megas ... Uma parte que que coloquei um foreach consome cerca de mais 15 megas ... Então estou tentando otimizar o código, apesar de estar rápido na sua execução. Então estou temeroso que em um momento mais a frente quando for ter que executar esse foreach com o dobro de dados possa causa um fatal error por consumo de memória

Comment: posta o código e vamos ver porque ! =P

Comment: muito obrigado pela sua atenção ... Eu editei a pergunta é coloquei informações complementares e o código também ...

Answer (score -3):

gc_collect_cycles();//Força a coleta de quaisquer ciclos de lixo existentes. Este comando funcionou muito bem para mim em um script de longa duração. Ele limpa a memoria no momento que você quiser.